# Всплывающий блок с сообщением на JS/jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте, хочу реализовать следующую идею: итак, когда 1 пользователь на сайте пишет сообщение другому пользователю, автоматически открывалось окно с его сообщением, чтоб другой пользователь мог ответить на сообщение в этом же окне или закрыть его, потом открыть и прочесть. Необязательно за меня все это реализовывать, главное объясните, как или подтолкните, с чего и как найти ответ для реализации идеи.

Comment: >  как или подтолкните, с чего и как найти ответ для реализации идеи.

Подталкиваю. Вот вам волшебные слова: comet, HTTP server push, websockets.

Comment: Если расскажете, что у вас на стороне сервера крутится, может быть смогу дать еще волшебных слов.

Answer (score 1):

На данный момент советую посмотреть в сторону `long polling`. В сети есть масса примеров реализации чата под разные сервера с использованием данной технологии.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно поставить `node.js` & `socket.io` на сервер, [пример](http://habrahabr.ru/post/127525/). Дальше просто - когда человек начинает вводить сообщение - слать отдельное сообщение на сервер о событии начала диалога, а сервер пересылает уже это сообщение тому кому пишут и показывает это сообщение.

Answer (score -1):

Достаточно постоянно проверять не поступило ли новых сообщений по таймеру. Чем меньше интервал - тем быстрее человек видит сообщение, но и тем выше нагрузка на сервер. Пока иначе никак, но ждем повсеместной поддержки "WebSocket".